# strong convexity second-order derivative

Tags: functional-analysis

When in general that for 2nd order differentiable strong convex function $f(x)$ with modulus $m$, that $x \in \mathbb{E}$ but $\nabla f \in E^*$ (the dual space), does that $\nabla^2 f \succeq m \mathrm{I}$ still holds? If not, is it true that the replacing property should be $\langle \nabla^2 f(x) ~l, l\rangle > m || ~l ~||^2, \forall l \in \mathbb{E}$?